# Drupal basic page doesn’t seem to use page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

Title says it really. Basic pages created in Drupal don’t seem to use the `page.tpl.php` file as a template.

If I edit the `html.tpl.php` file, those changes apply to every page, and it causes errors when I load a basic page.

I have also tried to copy the `page.tpl.php` file and name it `page—basic-page.tpl.php` to no avail.

Any idea what’s going on?

Also, how do I go about changing the page_top variable to include more content?
Lastly, the default `page.tpl.php` file has `$page` variables and things like `$page_top` and the like.

How would I call the title from the page only and the body text of a page only?

I’m using Drupal 7 and a custom sub theme.

The aforementioned files are in the template folder of the theme and I did clear caches when I added them.

Answer (score 3):

Add $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE; in settings.php and clear cache, reload page and check view source.
It will display the template file suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

page.tpl.php file common for all pages. Just print anything to the tpl and run any node of basic page as well as other content type page and check if its working or not. If page.tpl.php not working for basic page only, then check your template.php file.

For print a page title just need to use following code:

```
    <?php print $title; ?>
```

For print body text you need to use following:

```
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Comment: It is common, but that doesn't mean that it will always be used. It can be overridden, by creating page template for i.e. specific content type by following naming convention, or from code.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the theme you are using. But I guess you are actually meaning `page--page.tpl.php` (double dashes). Which will be taken into account after you added the following snippet to your theme's `template.php`. Replace `MYTHEME` with your theme's machine name.

> ```
> function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
>   if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
>    // If the content type's machine name is "my_machine_name" the file
>    // name will be "page--my-machine-name.tpl.php".
>    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['node']->type; // (double underscores)
>    }
> }
> ```

See [Template (theme hook) suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions), where I also got above snippet from.

Answer (score 0):

active theme debug for inspecting the template source and you get a different suggestions to user it (just avoid using node/nid).

commend drush to enable theme debug `drush vset theme_debug 1`